# Plupload browse button doesn't work in IE10

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer, plupload

I just put up a simple file upload with JS Plupload plugin system.
Just a button that opens the file explorer to select the file to download.

The system works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari but not in Internet Explorer.

**Javascript**

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    containes :     'plupload',
    browse_button : 'uploadBrowser',
    runtimes : 'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
    url :           'upload.php',
    multipart:      true,
    urlstream_upload: true,
    multipart_params:{directory: 'test'},
    max_file_size : '3mb',
    filters : [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,jpeg,png"}
    ]
});
```

Comment: What exactly happens? Have you tried hitting F12 and using the Script Debugger to watch for exceptions?

Comment: Yes, sous IE il ne se passe absolument rien. Alors j'ai fait un uploader.refresh() ou uploader.init(), mais ça ne marche pas non plus.

Answer (score 1):

Is the container that holds the uploader hidden on page load, or does it move in position at all?  I spent ages trying to work out why my Pluploader wasn't working in IE (8/9/10) only to realise that because my Pluplaoder was hidden on page load (or at the time of configuring the uploader), and then subsequently shown when needed, IE threw it's toys and the button stopped working.  All I ended up having to do was call `uploader.refresh();` to refresh the positioning of the uplaoder.